# An expression tree of Operators(AND, OR) and Operands(T/F)

Tags: math, data-structures

An expression tree of
 1. Operators: AND/OR
 2. Operands: class Operand(id: int, value: boolean)

Need to get the minimal number of false operand ids, whose values needs to be true to make complete expression tree evaluation to be true.

Comment: Can you please provide more details on this expression tree? Will operators only only occur between two operands on the tree? What is the relevance of the id in the `Operand` class? Are these operands intended to be only booleans? Are you referring to a sub-tree? If it could just be any tree containing operators and operands, the answer would be 0.

Comment: Yes expression tree is binary expression tree, operands are always leaf nodes, need to get subset of operands that values need to tweak to get expression tree evaluation: true

Comment: Makes sense. Does the sub-tree need to start at the root node or can it start anywhere?

Comment: subtree can start at any node, but we are looking final evaluation of expression tree. It's like, expression tree is already evaluated. So either final value is true or false. If it is evaluated to false, get the subset of operands that need a tweak in their values to make expression tree evaluation true